# SQL: Filter (rows) with maximum value within groups (columns)

Tags: sql

I need to filter for rows based on maximum values of version within month and location. Using SQL.

For example, I have table below where there are version 1 and 2 of June & NYC, I wanted to filter for only the row of version 2 with revenue 11. Or for January & NYC, I wanted to get only the row with revenue 15.

```
Month   Location Version    Revenue
June    NYC     1            10
June    NYC     2            11
June    LA      3            12
January NYC     1            13
January NYC     2            14
January NYC     3            15
January LA      1            16
January LA      2            17
```

Result:

```
Month   Location  Version   Revenue
June    NYC        2          11
June    LA         3          12
January NYC        3          15
January LA         2          17
```

Edit to change name of column to Revenue to remove confusion. I do not need the max value of revenue, only revenue that goes with max version of that month and that location.

Comment: Should the January NYC line in the result have 15 for value? That seems to be the pattern (max value). The Result section shows January NYC 3 and 14 (as opposed to 15).

Comment: I'm re-reading the question and am confused. Do you want, for a given Month and Location, the max Version and Value columns? That's what the Result seems to show, but the text asks for max Value. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, changed column name from value to revenue. I only need max version and whatever revenue that goes with it.

Comment: OK - in that case, I think you want the correlated subquery answer then. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use joins as an alternative to correlated subqueries, e.g.:

```
select t1.* from YourTable t1 inner join
(
    select t2.month, t2.location, max(t2.version) as mv
    from YourTable t2
    group by t2.month, t2.location
) q on t1.month = q.month and t1.location = q.location and t1.version = q.mv
```

Change `YourTable` to the name of your table.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that minimizes subqueries is to use the `row_number()` window function. (You don't mention *which* database server you're using, but most of them support it.)

```
SELECT month, location, version, revenue
FROM (SELECT month, location, version, revenue
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY month, location ORDER BY version DESC) AS rn
      FROM your_table)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical method is filtering using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.version = (select max(t2.version)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.month = t.month and t2.location = t.location
                  );
```